# Change image while mouse is over the image

Tags: html, css, image, web

At the moment I'm trying to develop an online shop with my friend and we would like that the image; once the mouse is over it; changes to second picture of the product. But as soon as the mouse isn't over it anymore, it needs to change back to the original image.

Much like [here](http://www.velt.ch/shop)

Thank you...

Comment: The word you seek is hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/2774m4ob/

HTML :

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://www.velt.ch/uploads/images/w254h254_art_49_8.jpg" class="img1">
  <img src="http://www.velt.ch/uploads/images/w254h254_art_49_9.jpg" class="img2">
</div>
```

and we will handle it with css :

```
.images{
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.images img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
.images .img2{
  z-index:2;
  display:none;
}
.images:hover .img2{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want the to look at the "mouseover" event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover

Answer (score 1):

The most well-known jQuery plugin that can be used to zoom parts of an image is cloudzoom, however it's non-free.

There are a lot of image zoom plugins in this page:

http://netfruits.com/2013/03/jquery-image-zoom-plugins/

Some nice free ones:

Easyzoom is probably the closest to what you require that is free, as you mentioned.
There's also elevate-zoom, which is free and looks quite nice.